# igraph: edges_from vs edges_to. What is the difference?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

Hi i have trouble to understand the difference between edges_from and edges_to atributes in an igraph.
Are those not the same? ie only the direction is different?

The size of a vectors seems to be similar and what are the `to` and `from` refering to in a graph?

BR.

Comment: Is the graph directed? If it is, then the direction is, well, important...

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us in which situation you get these attributes? Thanks